# Incorrect encoding redirect url when I using ServiceWorker fetch. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, encoding, service-worker

I have a trouble with ServiceWorker. It works OK for all requests excluding 301 redirect. I'm using cyrilic URLs, but it works without ServiceWorker.

When I send request without ServiceWorker I recieve correct response with correct URL to redirect. When I use ServiceWorker it respond incorrect URL. I respond "**/ÐÐ½Ð°ÑÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ-ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð°--Ð¨Ð¾ÑÑ-Ð²-ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð°ÑÐµ-Ð£ÑÐ°ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð°**" (it's ISO-8859-1, but I don't know where it appear, in respond I see UTF-8 and sw.js saved in UTF-8). What happen? Please, help and notify how can I fix it? What I need to read?

I'm using PHP and NGINX.

Thanks to everyone in advance for help!

**Without ServiceWorker:**

Request:

```
Request URL: https://glosum.ru/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0--%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%A3%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301 
Remote Address: 194.58.104.159:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response:

```
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 30 Oct 2019 17:41:19 GMT
location: /Значение-слова--Шост-в-словаре-Ушакова
server: nginx
status: 301
```

**With ServiceWorker:**

Request:

```
Request URL: https://glosum.ru/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0--%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%A3%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301 
Remote Address: 194.58.104.159:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response:

```
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 30 Oct 2019 17:41:27 GMT
location: /ÐÐ½Ð°ÑÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ-ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð°--Ð¨Ð¾ÑÑ-Ð²-ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð°ÑÐµ-Ð£ÑÐ°ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð°
server: nginx
status: 301
```

My service worker source code:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('v5')
            .then(function (cache) {
                return cache.addAll([
                    '/',
                    '/js/share.js',
                    // img
                    '/img/logo.png',
                    '/images/search.png',
                    '/img/books.webp',
                    '/img/books.jpg',
                    '/img/header.png',
                    '/img/nav.png',
                    '/img/footer.png',
                    '/img/main-shadow.png',
                    '/img/article-1books.jpg',
                    // css
                    '/css/style.css'
                ]);
            })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                }
                return fetch(event.request);
            })
    );
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your service worker's `fetch` handler? Seeing the code would help understand what your service worker is doing.

Comment: Thanks, I added full service worker source code to question.

Comment: @artourer, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Amir no, I didn't fix it. Just turn off cache and commented out line `return response` in fetch event.